# Don't know why the if condition is not detecting if the operand is an object or not

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In the bottom of this question I have code:             `console.log("returnAnonModel -----", returnAnonModel, "typeof : ", typeof returnAnonModel)` ,it logs that `returnAnonModel` is an object. I don't understand why the if else conditions don't get hit.

First let me show you what it logs:

```
returnAnonModel ----- { _id: 57d0d00c50ed1a2421749a69,
  __v: 0,
  usefulness: [],
  reviews: [] } typeof :  object
```

The question is straight forward. you see the object but apparently `Object.keys(returnAnonModel).length > 0` in the if condition is not true. shouldn't the object have a length of 4? shouldn't I see the console inside that if? `console.log("***********Anon USER SEARCHING*********************************")` doesn't show

Code:

```
    var modelType = undefined;
    Anon.findOne({_id : app.locals.user._id})
    .then(function( returnAnonModel){
        console.log("returnAnonModel -----", returnAnonModel, "typeof : ", typeof returnAnonModel)
        if(err) console.log(err);
        if( Object.keys(returnAnonModel).length > 0 ){
            console.log("***********Anon USER SEARCHING*********************************")
            modelType = Anon
            userOrAnonArr()
        }else{
            console.log("***********USER USER SEARCHING*********************************")
            modelType = User
            userOrAnonArr(modelType)
        }

        function userOrAnonArr(modelType){
        console.log("modelType: ", modelType, " app.locals.user._id : ", typeof app.locals.user._id )
        modelType.findOne({_id : app.locals.user._id}, function(err, returnUser){
            if(err) console.log(err);
            console.log("returnUser : ", returnUser )
```

SOMETHING ELSE IS WEIRD: 
I tried to test the length of the object by doing this:
`console.log("Object.keys(returnAnonModel).length", Object.keys(returnAnonModel).length)`

and it returns `Object.keys(returnAnonModel).length 10` so the length is 10. I think mongoose adds properties.

but when I do

`console.log("Object.keys(returnAnonModel).length", Object.keys(returnAnonModel).toObject().length)`

it logs absolutely nothing. why?

The last **Edit**

This works. I was trying to do this functionality this whole time. And I don't know why it works now and not before. I think it has something to do with the console.

```
    var modelType = undefined;
    Anon.findOne({_id : app.locals.user._id})
    .then(function( returnAnonModel){
        console.log("*******", returnAnonModel ,"***********88")
        // console.log("returnAnonModel -----", returnAnonModel, "typeof : ", typeof returnAnonModel)
        // console.log("Object.keys(returnAnonModel).length", Object.keys(returnAnonModel.toObject()).length)
        // console.log("returnAnonModel.toObject()---", returnAnonModel.toObject())

        if(returnAnonModel){
            modelType = Anon;
            userOrAnonArr(modelType);
            console.log("*************Anon user found*********************");
        }else{
            modelType = User;
            userOrAnonArr(modelType);
            console.log("*************Anon user NOT found*************")
        }
```

Comment: Objects don't have a length (unless you give it one), you're thinking of Array - oh, wait, `Object.keys(yourobject)` would have a length! How odd

Comment: what is `.toObejct`?

Comment: `if(err) console.log(err);` - where is err defined?

Comment: I see what your saying about toObject() .  I changed it to `Object.keys(returnAnonModel.toObject()).length` and now it returns `4`. the `err` part was from old code. I took it out now.

Comment: Ok I changed the if condition to `Object.keys(returnAnonModel.toObject()).length > 0` and I get the proper console. but now the user makes an operation where `returnAnonModel` is `null` and the typeof is `object`. the problem now is that it doesn't hit the else condition. shouldn't it hit the else condition on `null` ? tried `else if(returnAnonModel == null)` and didn't work.

Comment: check for null first

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve.  It sounds like you're down a dark alley with `Object.keys(xxx).length` and asking about issues with that when you should be describing your actual problem and we'll help you with a much better way to solve that.

Comment: I wanted to search an `Anon` collection and if the user doesn't exist in the `Anon` got to the user collection. I did this before but now I tried to do it differently. I want to first check Anon and see if it is null (it should be null when app.locals._id is not in Anon collection) then set a var `modelType` to `User` if it is null . If it is not `null` set the `modelType` to `Anon` I wanted to use `modelType` in a function later. I couldn't get the if conditions to work., It's not the first time I tested something against null. I don't know what the problem is. the returned doc says null.

Comment: Have you done a `console.log(returnAnonModel)` and `console.log(typeof returnAnonModel)` to see exactly what it is in the case where you want to match it with an `if` statement.  You and we need to know exactly what the value is that you want to match with an `if` statement in order to know how to best match it.  Right now, it appears you're taking stabs in the dark without knowing what result you are actually testing for.  `Object.keys()` is not an appropriate way to test the type of an object.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. I tried consoling the log with just the `returnAnonModel` and now it works :). I find it weird that it works now and not before. can you pleas explain why. I know you have a lot experience. I showed the simple code in the last EDIT of this question.

Comment: I asked a question about it. I think it's important .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39402908/i-cant-test-if-mongoose-returned-a-document

Answer (score 0):

The `Object.keys()` function doesn't cover all properties of an object. It only includes properties that meet the following 2 criteria:

1. The property must be an "owned" property, meaning that `Object.keys()` does *not* look along any prototype chain that may exist.
2. The property must have been defined with the `enumerable` attribute.

It's not clear from the code provided how the `returnAnonModel` object has been constructed, but my guess is that the properties do not meet both of the criteria listed.