# I can't test if mongoose returned a document. Console.log() might be causing problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

Why doesn't the below code hit the if condition?

The `console.log("returnAnonModel -----", returnAnonModel, "typeof : ", typeof returnAnonModel)` returns

```
returnAnonModel ----- [ { _id: 57d21d2deaa0c4c8297311a6,
    __v: 0,
    usefulness: [],
    reviews: [] } ] typeof :  object
```

The code:

```
    Anon.find({_id : app.locals.user._id})
    .then(function( returnAnonModel){
        console.log("returnAnonModel -----", returnAnonModel, "typeof : ", typeof returnAnonModel)
        console.log("Object.keys(returnAnonModel).length", Object.keys(returnAnonModel.toObject()).length)
        console.log("returnAnonModel.toObject()---", returnAnonModel.toObject())
        if(returnAnonModel){
            console.log("*************Anon user found*********************");
        }else{
            console.log("Anon user NOT found--")
        }
```

EDIT :  I just tried `if(returnAnonModel.length){` and still the logs in the if or else don't get displayed

EDIT2 : I changed it to below and now it works. why? Is it because I have the `returnAnonModel` it the console 2 times I know this time I use `findOne` instead of `find`. What is the main difference?

```
    Anon.findOne({_id : app.locals.user._id})
    .then(function( returnAnonModel){
        console.log("*******", returnAnonModel ,"***********88")
        // console.log("returnAnonModel -----", returnAnonModel, "typeof : ", typeof returnAnonModel)
        // console.log("Object.keys(returnAnonModel).length", Object.keys(returnAnonModel.toObject()).length)
        // console.log("returnAnonModel.toObject()---", returnAnonModel.toObject())

        if(returnAnonModel){
            console.log("*************Anon user found*********************");
        }else{
            console.log("*************Anon user NOT found*************")
        }
```

Comment: So, with `.find()`, `returnAnonModel` is an array of objects and probably with `.findOne()`, the result is just a single object, not an array of objects.

Comment: Since I'm not aware of any  `.toObject()` method on an array, that line is probably throwing an exception, thus it doesn't get to your `if` statement and because you don't have a `.catch()` handler after that, the rejected promise caused by the exception goes unhandled and perhaps unnoticed.  One possible answer - always have error handling so you can see these issues.

Comment: I thought it was ok to use `.toObject()` like the way I did because you can convert mongoose arrays and docs to regular objects by using `.toObject()` http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.toObject .
And I was using a `catch()` to notify me of error and non came up